# Extract Mobile Numbers from text file Starting with 0300 or 0321. Like 0300-XXXXXXX, 0321-XXXXXXX

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, regex

How can I extract only mobile numbers from my text file? Mobile numbers format is `03xx-xxxxxxx`.

Text is something like this:

> 1 Mr.Pervaiz Ahmad Latifi Rajput Traders, W/571, Ratta Road, Near
>   Novalty Cinema, Rawalpindi Tel:5774972,5775283,0300-5358177 Fax #
>   E-mail: www. -
>
> 2 Mr.Ashraf Raza Khan Imran Aluminium Works, Shop # 06, 73-A, Usman
>   Pura, Rawalpindi Tel:0300-9544837 Fax # E-mail: www. -

I need to extract mobile numbers and list them one by one in a new line. For example:

```
03005358177
03009544837
03xxxxxxxxx
03xxxxxxxxx
```

Please let me know all steps accordingly as I know nothing. I really appreciate your quick & kind help!

Comment: A regular expression to match phone numbers is very common there are also hundreds of examples.  What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know regex neither worked in excel :(

Comment: If you'd like to do this in Excel, edit your question to say so specifically.  (You say "text file", which is a very different thing). There might be an excel search that'll do it for you (I wouldn't know).

Comment: @user257912 - You said nothing about Excel in your question. Your question isn't clear and is likely to be closed at this rate. I am pretty sure VBS ( Visual Basic Script ) supports Regular Expressions thus Excel should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to superuser.sx. Be aware that this site is for people who'll do a little work themselves-- It's not a good fit for questions about which you "know nothing".

You can do what you're looking for with "regular expressions". For example, you can match numbers of the form `03xx-xxxxxxx` with the regular expression `/\b03\d\d-\d{7}\b/`.

Many programming and scripting languages include regular expressions, and there are even websites where you can upload a text file and experiment with searching it. Check them out and come back when you have more specific questions.

Comment: Finally, I have found the way & extracted mobile numbers from text doc. Now, they are formatted one by one in a new line. for example:
03008565710
03335214569
0922563141
0515792424
But I want to delete the number lines which are not starting with 03xxXXXXXXX
?

Comment: If you are on Linux or OS X, use `egrep '^03' numbers.txt > mobiles.txt`. If you're on Windows, clarify that in your question or download one of the many grep-lookalikes (e.g., `grepWin` might be able to do it). And read up on regular expressions, they have many uses.